# Excel VBA taking user input to check a cell across multiple sheets and save specific sheets for later use

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA, and trying to write a program in excel that will allow me to manually input a row and column into a program. The program should then check the specified cell in multiple sheets to see if it's a 1 or 0. If it's a 0, then I need the specific worksheet that it was in to be saved and identified later in an output box.

Below is what I have so far. The parts I'm unsure about are the saving the specified worksheet, and specifying the cell used to check from the input box (IE if Cj.range(D H) vs Cj.cell(DH) etc.).

```
Option Explicit
Sub Trial1()
Dim Hr As Single
Dim D As Single

Do
D = InputBox("Please enter the day you would like to study. Monday = A, Tuesday = B, Wed = C, Thurs = D, Fri = E, Sat = F, Sun = G.")
Hr = InputBox("Please enter the hour you would like to study in military time.")
If Hr >= 7 Or Hr <= 22 Then Exit Do
Loop
Call worksheet1()
End Sub

Sub worksheet1()

Dim Availability() As String
Dim C1 As Worksheet
Dim C2 As Worksheet
Dim C3 As Worksheet
Dim C4 As Worksheet
Dim C5 As Worksheet
Dim C6 As Worksheet
Dim C7 As Worksheet
Dim C8 As Worksheet
Dim C9 As Worksheet

Set C1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("3043")
Set C2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("2222")
Set C3 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("2205")
Set C4 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("3138")
Set C5 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("1011")
Set C6 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("1012")
Set C7 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("1016")
Set C8 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("1219")
Set C9 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("2245")

Do
For j = 1 To 9
    If Cj.Range(DHr) = 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve Availability(0 To UBound(Availability) + 1) As String
    End If
Next j
```

Possible Alternative

```
'For i = 1 To N
'If Worksheets(i).Cells(H, D).Value = 0 Then MsgBox ("There is room available in room sheet" & i & ".")
'If Worksheets(i).Cells(H, D).Value = 1 Then MsgBox ("ROOM")
'Next i
```

Comment: You may want to include an 'Option Explicit' at the top of all code to see where you have referenced variables that are not defined. Is it ok to just return a string containing all sheet names where the condition is met (i.e. 'Sheet2, SheetA, Sheet5'?

Comment: Yeah, Each sheet is a different location, the rows are the time of day and the columns are the days of the week. I need the program to be able to just list off all the sheets with an availability at the given/input time. I have renamed the sheets such that they are the location, and I have the hourly blocks split up into either 0 or 1, 0 if available, 1 if unavailable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I clarified the msgbox at the end: Either NO places available, or list of 'places' (which happens to be the worksheet name).

Here is an example of how to spin through the desired sheets and find which ones have a zero in the desired row/column.  You could pass the list back to the calling subroutine, or just deal with it where they are found.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Trial1()
Dim Hr  As Long
Dim D   As Long

    Do
        D = InputBox("Please enter the day you would like to study. Monday = 1, Tuesday = 2, Wed = 3, Thurs = 4, Fri = 5, Sat = 6, Sun = 7.")
        Hr = InputBox("Please enter the hour you would like to study in military time.")
        If Hr >= 7 Or Hr <= 22 Then Exit Do
    Loop
    Call Check_Sheets(Hr, D)
End Sub

Function Check_Sheets(lRow As Long, lCol As Long)
Dim Availability()  As String
Dim i               As Integer
Dim ws              As Worksheet
Dim iAvail          As Integer
Dim strMSG          As String

' Note: I included the "'" as a delimiter in case the combined numbers give a false sheet name.
Const SheetNames = "'3043'2222'2205'3138'1011'1012'1016'1219'2245"

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets              ' Find all worksheets
        If InStr(1, SheetNames, "'" & ws.Name) > 0 Then     ' Is this a sheet we want?
            If ws.Cells(lRow, lCol).value & "" = 0 Then     ' Is the cell = 0 (warning: make sure no null values else!)
                iAvail = iAvail + 1                         ' Count as available
                ReDim Preserve Availability(iAvail)
                Availability(iAvail) = ws.Name              ' Save sheet name
            End If
        End If
    Next ws

    ' List Available Sheets
    If iAvail > 0 Then
        strMSG = "Area 1, 2 and 3 as saved in Array" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf     'This is the part I'm unsure about (TheBanks)
        For i = 1 To iAvail
            Debug.Print "Available: " & Availability(i)
            strMSG = strMSG & Availability(i) & vbCrLf
        Next
        MsgBox strMSG, vbOKOnly, "The Following Areas Are Available"
    Else
        MsgBox "There were NO places available", vbOKOnly, "None Available"
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I needed. The program now outputs the specific row and column that it is searching for. I need it to output the specific names of the sheets that has a 0 in that cell in a message.

Comment: Did you see the message box displayed? If so, were there any sheet names mentioned? If not, that means none of the sheets had that cell set to 0.

Comment: The message box was displayed, however it said "The following worksheets had a zero in row 11 column 3" I need it to say something like "The following places are available: Worksheet 1, worksheet 4 and worksheet 6" or whatever the availability array stored the worksheet names as.

Comment: OK, I am confused. The existing message box would list the 'places' (aka worksheet names) where there was a zero in the desired cell. I updated the answer to say be clear if none are found. Are you saying you never saw a list of 'places' in the messagebox? Please try the updated code and it will list the 'places' - if any are found. Please let me know the result - either none or names.

Comment: I like the loop that you added for the nothing found. It seems like the problem now is the 1Row and 1Col is saving the coordinates for the cell on the line "strMSG = "The following places are available. In stead of the part that restates the coordinates given, the sheet name should be given.

With that new loop you added, it keeps saying NO places available at times it shouldn't.

Comment: The above code works for me (I forgot to include 'Dim i As Integer'). I created 3 sheets and named them like yours. Knowing I will test with Day 1, Time 7, I then placed a '1' in the first sheet in Row 7, Col 1. The second sheet has a '0' on R7C1; the third sheet I left empty - thus the cell is NULL. I get a messagebox that says ONE sheet (2222) is available. So, if this does not work for you, then please answer two questions: (1) Are your cells NULL? They are supposed to be 0 or 1. (2) Do you assume 7 AM is row 7 or do you adjust to make it row 1?

Comment: Holy crap, it worked! You are a godsend there Wayne! Thank you kindly.

Comment: Hah! Even my broken watch is right twice a day. Can I accept part of your suggested edit (Dim i...)? You suggest a message like 'Area 1, Area 2 and Area 3...' whereas I just list them out in order. You can make the message any format you want, but I don't want to get into a format discussion for a message that you can control any way you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do with the workbook names would be better done as an array.  Although it isn't a whole solution, there are other problems, like if the user inputs lower case.

```
Dim C(0 To 8) As String
Dim tRange As String
Dim tSheet As String

C(0) = "3043"
C(1) = "2222"
C(2) = "2205"
C(3) = "3138"
C(4) = "1011"
C(5) = "1012"
C(6) = "1016"
C(7) = "1219"
C(8) = "2245"

For j = 0 To 8
tSheet = C(j)     ' of course you can skip this line and just insert C(j) into Sheets()
tRange = Chr(34) & D & Hr & Chr(34)
    If Sheets(tSheet).Range(tRange) = 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve Availability(0 To UBound(Availability) + 1) As String
    End If
Next j
```

Comment: Do you think this would be better as a subprogram, a function or neither?

Comment: Are you asking how to pass arguments into a function or method?  Instead of using Input Boxes?  Pass them straight from another value, such as a textbox or dateTimePicker on a form?  This answer is more just addressing how to get the variable to control the sheet

Comment: You might be looking for something like 'Sub UseNumbers( X as Long, Y as Long)' that would take X and Y and use them somehow.  Then you would call it: 'Call UseNumbers(4, 5)'  Or if it was a function, you would say 'result = UseNumbers(4,5)'

Comment: I think that might be how I'm going to try to evolve the program. I like the base that Wayne posted above, but I think I am going to use the X and Y idea to compare two different sites.

If I was to do that I would want to compare two different arrays, by size and disregarding either the X or the Y that is smaller. Like a Linear program, Maximize zeta = Summation(X's)+Summation(Y's) with the constraint of if X>Y then y=0, and if Y>X then x=0